# Set Base currency in magento2 by programmatically

Tags: magento2, currency, stores

I am trying to set base currency pro-grammatically with below code.

```
class Currency extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  protected $_storeManager;
   public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
     array $data = []
      ) {     
      $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
   public function execute() {  
    $currencyCode = 'USD';
    $this->_storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currencyCode);

  }
}
```

The above code is not setting the base currency, can anyone tell me where i am wrong? Thanks in Advance!!.

**Update**

I followed Rohan answer, then getting below error.

[image]

Here product prices in basket showing with changed currency, but order summary still showing with the old currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For base currency change, I would like to recommend you to change from admin configuration.

> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Currency Setup -> Currency Options -> Base Currency

For programmatically, You need to inject this below code in your construct :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_configInterface;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface $configInterface
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_configInterface = $configInterface;
    ....
}
```

Then, you need to use this below line in your function :

```
$currency_code = "USD";
$this->_configInterface->saveConfig('currency/options/base', $currency_code, $store = \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
```

**Hope, It will useful for you.**

Comment: Tried your answer, didn't work @Rohan

Comment: Can you please remove generated and clean cache? Because, I tried and it's working fine so.

Comment: You want to change value of Store -> Configuration -> General -> Currency Setup -> Currency Options -> Base Currency but programmatically. Right?

Comment: Yes cleared generated and flushed cache also, this code setting code in db, but in frontend all prices are showing with INR only

Comment: Yes exactly, Once that is changed, All product prices show in that currency?

Comment: Yes. I changed from USD to Qatar Rial and it's display all product with Qatar Rial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97332/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-manjunath).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $this->_storeManager->getStore()->setBaseCurrentCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
```

OR

```
   $this->_storeManager->getStore()->setBaseCode($currencyCode);
```

Comment: No, not working @padhiyar..